# Youtube API - div over flash object

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, wmode

I am trying to set a div over the youtube video.I have tried setting wmode:transparent and opaque but the video disappears.Is there any other way?

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always"};
swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?&video_id=9_So9QyozqQ&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
        "ytplayer", "229", "209", "8", null, null, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swf object is a `windowed element`. Windowed elements are always drawn over `windowless elements`, and unfortunately most other html elements are indeed windowless.

Another `windowed element` is an `iframe`. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378) link. A way to accomplish what you want is to use an iFrame to mask the swf object. You can place the iframe on top of the swf object by giving it a higher `z-index`. You can then make the iframe transparent, which basically cuts a hole in your `windowed elements` layer, showing the underlying windowless elements.

Cheers